Populating values based on 1 match per category in SQL
Here is the test code Code
 with  Test as
( select 'A' as Cat, 'AB' as Typ from dual
  union 
select 'A' as Cat, 'AC' as Typ from dual
  union 
select 'A' as Cat, 'AE' as Typ from dual
  union
  select 'B' as Cat, 'AC' as Typ from dual
  union 
select 'C' as Cat, 'AB' as Typ from dual
  UNION 
SELECT 'C' as Cat, 'AE' AS Typ from dual) 

select  (case when Typ = 'AB' then 1 else 0 end) as N,
  (case when Typ = 'AB' then row_number() over (partition by Cat order by Cat asc) end) as r,
   Cat, Typ from Test;

Here is the Output I get,

Expected Output:
I want the entire category to get populated with 1 when there is atleast 1 match with value 'AB' for that category
Either 1 of the below outputs is desired.


Is this not just a case of conditional count as a window function count(case when Typ = 'AB' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by cat)

Which rdbms do you use?

It might be simplest to just use an exists predicate to check for your ab value

You could leverage your query and adapt it as:
 with  Test as
( select 'A' as Cat, 'AB' as Typ from dual
  union 
select 'A' as Cat, 'AC' as Typ from dual
  union 
select 'A' as Cat, 'AE' as Typ from dual
  union
  select 'B' as Cat, 'AC' as Typ from dual
  union 
select 'C' as Cat, 'AB' as Typ from dual
  UNION 
SELECT 'C' as Cat, 'AE' AS Typ from dual),

calc AS (
select  (case when Typ = 'AB' then 1 else 0 end) as N,
  (case when Typ = 'AB' then row_number() over (partition by Cat order by Cat asc) end) as r,
   Cat, Typ from Test
)

SELECT
  Test.Cat
  , Test.Typ
  , b.output
FROM Test
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT
  max(N) as output
  , CAT
FROM calc
GROUP BY CAT
) as b ON Test.Cat = b.CAT
;

Essentially, we use the max(N) function and GROUP BY CAT in order to have a single record of 1 or 0 for each category. We then join this result back into your original Test table on the value of CAT, which will propagate the 1 or 0 to all the records.

You are on the right track, just use max() instead of row_number()
If all typ's are not 'AB' across the cat, the max will be 0. If any is 'AB' the max will be 1.
with Test as
( select 'A' as Cat, 'AB' as Typ from dual
  union 
select 'A' as Cat, 'AC' as Typ from dual
  union 
select 'A' as Cat, 'AE' as Typ from dual
  union
  select 'B' as Cat, 'AC' as Typ from dual
  union 
select 'C' as Cat, 'AB' as Typ from dual
  UNION 
SELECT 'C' as Cat, 'AE' AS Typ from dual) 

select t.*,
       max(case when typ = 'AB' then 1 else 0 end) over
         ( partition by cat ) as output_1
  from test t

